# Release object in Cocos2d app

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a class called RestClient that implements NSURLConnectionDataDelegate.

In a CCLayerColor class, Menu, (the menu of my cocos2d app) I have a property of type RestClient defined like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) RestClient *rc;
```

In the onEnterTransitionDidFinish I have the following code:

```
[super onEnterTransitionDidFinish];


AppController *appDel = (AppController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if (appDel.FreeVersion) {

    if (!self.rc) {
        self.rc = [[RestClient alloc] init]; //released in dealloc
    }

    [rc GetMessage];
}
```

The dealloc of the Menu class looks like this:

```
    - (void) dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Menu dealloc");
    [rc release];
    [super dealloc];

}
```

After I exit the Menu I see that the dealloc is called, but after [rc release] **I don't see the dealloc of the RestClient** firing. **Any idea why?**

Here is the code in the RestClient class:

```
@implementation RestClient



-(void)GetMessage
{


    NSString *lng = NSLocalizedString(@"lng",nil);

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://MyLink/%@", [lng uppercaseString]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    messageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    [messageData appendData:data];

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //show the message
    if (!errorReceivingMessage) {

        id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:messageData options:kNilOptions error:nil];


        msgDict = (NSDictionary*)json;
        NSString *msgText = [msgDict objectForKey:@"MessageText"];
        NSString * msgTitle = [msgDict objectForKey:@"MessageTitle"];
        NSString * buyButtonText = [msgDict objectForKey:@"BuyButtonText"];
        NSString *cancelButtonText = [msgDict objectForKey:@"CancelButtonText"];

        [messageData release];
        UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:msgTitle message:msgText delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonText
                                             otherButtonTitles: buyButtonText , nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
         openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://someLink"]];
    }

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    if (messageData) {
        [messageData release];
    }
    errorReceivingMessage = YES;


}

-(void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Dealloc RestClient");
    //[messageData release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are not using ARC. If so do this:

```
self.rc = [[[RestClient alloc] init] autorelease]; //released in dealloc
```

In non-arc I believe strong is the same as retain. Which means you are creating it with init (so it will need to be released) then retaining it with the property. So you'll need two releases.

Comment: I will give it a try later and comeback with and answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `release` while using ARC

If you are rewriting `dealloc` method under ARC you mustn't call `[super dealloc]`, because it's generated by the compiler automatically